# User login through JSON request returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I am using Drupal 8.6.4

```
http://example.org/user/login?_format=json
```

When I try to submit a post request, it returns HTML page instead of JSON response.

I am sending headers:

```
  Content-Type: application/json
```

and data as:

```
 { "name": "admin" , "pass": "admin" }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: how did you make the post request, you sent the body as `Body Raw`, i have tested it with this and it works it return `{
    "current_user": {
        "uid": "1",
        "roles": [
            "authenticated",
            "administrator",
        ],
        "name": "Admin"
    },
    "csrf_token": "e9dWDT505MjVlxhJfmH-CYFoeBAodyzASGUB98B8Fuk",
    "logout_token": "8ZAv1Pyd0YBEsBV4maTgeLN6rkuOt70Pa3pSMEUvpkA"
}`

Comment: Hi @berramou  ,  yes I am sending it as raw , but I am getting logged in HTML page.  The return value is not json.  I am using Postman for testing.

Comment: make sure that type of raw is JSON (application/json)

Comment: Yes, I have set it Content-Type: application/json  . But I am not sure why it is giving me HTML.  It should have worked, but I am still unable to fix it.

Comment: I have figured it. Turns out that Redirect after login was redirecting to the given URL which resulted in HTML output. I have disabled that and now I am getting proper JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the [Redirect after login](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect_after_login) module was redirecting to the given URL, which resulted in HTML being output. I have disabled that and now I am getting the proper JSON response.